# Can we use :xdo_user_name for filter logic with WebLogic?

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

Can we use `:xdo_user_name` for filter logic with WebLogic?

I created a datamodel in oracle BI Publisher，with where clause like below:

```
WHERE (EMPLOYEE_NO = :xdo_user_name)
```

which works normally if I login with an employee account.

But I would like to make it show all data when I login as 'weblogic'，so I changed it to:

```
WHERE (EMPLOYEE_NO = :xdo_user_name
OR (CASE WHEN :xdo_user_name = 'weblogic' THEN 1=1 END))
```

Error is shown:

> Character dat， right truncation occurred:for example， an update or insert value is a string that is too long for the column， or a datetime value cannot be assigned to a host variable， because it is too small.

Not so sure about why this error show up. Please advise.

Comment: `OR (CASE WHEN :xdo_user_name = 'weblogic' THEN 1=1 END)` is the same as `OR :xdo_user_name = 'weblogic'` ? Anyway... how is the value bound, by position or by name? If by position then you might be picking up the wrong value somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```sql
WHERE EMPLOYEE = CASE WHEN :xdo_user_name = 'weblogic' THEN EMPLOYEE ELSE :xdo_user_name END
```

this way, when logged in as 'weblogic', where condition will return True for every row - otherwise it will be True just for rows where EMPLOYEE = :xdo_user_name.
Regards...